# Understanding for loop in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Hello there I was coding in pandas when I found this problem:

```
for label,content in data_temp.items():
    print(len(label))#Como vemos aqui nos imprime 

print(len(data_temp.columns))
```

Firstly, I was trying to print the label, which is the indicator of the column, right? It outputs these different numbers.

**7
9
9
7
10
12
8
24
9
11
11
15
13
17
11
18
5
12
16
12
9
5
8
12
5
12
12
15
11
14
17
10
9
6
9
11
9
7
14
14
15
10
23
12
5
15
12
16
10
15
17
17
8
9
7
7
22
34**

And when i print the `print(len(data_temp.columns))` it outputs:

**58**

Why does the `data_temp.columns` gives me a different number from the label in the for loop `data_temp.item()`? Aren't the labels of the for loop the indices of the `data_temp.columns`?

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the length of the labels, not the labels themselves.

Try `print(label)` and `print(data_temp.columns)` that should output the labels one by one in the for loop and then the name of the columns as a list